# UIPanGestureRecognizer does not have a member named touchesBegan

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift, ios8

I’m trying to subclass UIPanGestureRecognizer, and I think I might be doing something dumb. I’m getting errors when trying to override the methods that UIPanGestureRecognizer inherits from UIGestureRecognizer.

I have this code

```
class VPGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event);
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event);
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event);
    }
}
```

which is producing these errors

[image]

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer doesn't have such methods. because it is not a subclass of UIResponder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to override the functions, you can just define them like below. But I am not exactly sure why that is. In a custom `UIView` these functions have to be overridden.

```
func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    println("here")
}

func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

}

func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

}

func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

}
```

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks! I must have been reading the documentation wrong.

Comment: @matthewpalmer you didn't. You need to `import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass`

Answer (score 16):

Current accepted answer is not quite right, actually, if you want to subclass a UIGestureRecognizer, you should import the ***UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h*** header file, which described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html, see **Subclassing Notes** section.

As in Swift, this can be done as flow:

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass
```

then you are ready to go.

Comment: That should be the answer.